# Python anaconda ERROR 6: GEOS support not enabled

Tags: macos, python-3.x, anaconda, gdal, geos

I use anaconda3 on MacOS 10.11.3.

OSGEO and GDAL install from anaconda cloud. Also install packages from http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks.

I try:

`point.Within(polygon)` (osgeo library)

But I get the error: `ERROR 6: GEOS support not enabled`

How fix this?